# Task Scheduler not responding when attempting to create a new trigger on all Windows 2008 R2 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Issue: Task Scheduler not responding when attempting to create a new trigger or edit a trigger in Windows 2008 R2

The issue happens on *ALL* our Windows 2008 R2 servers.  The issue happens regardless of which user account I log on with.

I also notice that once Task Scheduler freezes and I close it, I can re-open task scheduler and sometimes I am able to edit a trigger or create a new trigger.

Here is the full error message from event viewer regarding the Task Scheduler:
[image: screen capture of Task Scheduler error]

Comment: I did read elsewhere that action disable all task history, then enable all task history may help.  So I'll try that to start.

Comment: Disable all task history and then enable all task history did not resolve the issue.

Comment: What is your CPU architecture on that server  ?

Comment: Intel Xeon x5660 @ 2.80 GHz 2.80 GHz (2 processors), running via VMWare 6.0

Comment: Do you have VMtools installed and was the OS updated, or is it the untouched original version ?

Comment: @Overmind  I have VMWare tools installed.  VMWare tools status is running and current.  VMWare VSphere 6.0.  Windows OS patches are current.

Comment: Well, most likely it's one of the patches, but in such cases it's not too easy to identify which one. You would have to know when the problem occurred and try removing patches that applied just before that.

Comment: @Overmind The clock on Windows Server 2008 is ticking... It's almost time to retire these servers.  Seeing as this isn't more than an annoyance, I think we'll just let it go.

Comment: i still prefer using old OS'es for various purposes. And if the new Windows Server works as 'well' as W10, i'll just skip it and that's it. I try to Linux everything when possible anyway.

Comment: I am on Windows Server 2016 on VMWare. Same issue still in 2020 :-(

Comment: Ups perhaps I was lying. It "only" took some 5min for a dialog to appear??!?!

Comment: @MartinDobšík Still an issue on Windows 2016!  Good ol' Microsoft :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this may seem like a dumb question, but have you tried just waiting for the process to complete? Don't terminate the frozen window or anything. That has actually been my problem. I ended the task before it could complete every time, so the problem "persisted" until one day I just waited and after a couple minutes, it reverted to normal.

Comment: Yes I have tried waiting twenty minutes or more.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this on a particular client machine.  For me, creating and saving the task without a trigger, and then editing the task to add the trigger seems to be more reliable.